# Fastest way to take screenShot of UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I've searched a lot but only found two methods to take screen shot of UIView.
first `renderInContext:`
I've used it in a way

```
CGContextRef context = [self createBitmapContextOfSize:CGSizeMake(nImageWidth, nImageHeight)];
CGAffineTransform flipVertical = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, nImageHeight);
CGContextConcatCTM(context, flipVertical);
[self.layer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
[self.layer renderInContext:context];
CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
UIImage* background = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: cgImage];
CGImageRelease(cgImage);
```

Second `drawViewHierarchyInRect:` which I've used as

```
UIImage *background = nil;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions (self.bounds.size, NO, self.window.screen.scale);

if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:)])
{
    [self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];   
}
background = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

I know that the second one is faster than first and it work for me for iPhone because the view has low size. but when I capturing from iPad the video become jerky. 
Can Any body tell me faster way of taking screen shot.
any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: I don't get it. Why you call `success = [self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];` twice? May be call it once. Try without if-statement.

Comment: What are you using the screenshot for? Is it for a background in another view? Also, which iOS version are you targeting?

Comment: @Fogmeister: Screen shots are using to write video file from it.i give it to AVAssetWriter to write video.  7 & 8 are targeting iOS version.

Comment: @Cy-4AH: I've tried this too but actually the problem is in drawViewHierarchyInRect: it take time to get screen shot image

Comment: What is the actual contents of the image that you are capturing? Where does it come from? Is it using camera contents? Or is it some sort of UIKit animation? etc...

Comment: Also, have a look at @Cy-4AH comment. You are running the code `[self drawViewHierarchy...]` twice. Once inside the if statement and then once after the if statement. There is no need for this and it will just be slowing down your code.

Comment: Oh sorry that was mistakenly added.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding performance, the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1817/_index.html) state the following:

> In addition to -drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:, UIView
>   now provides another two snapshot related methods,
>   -snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates: and -resizableSnapshotViewFromRect:afterScreenUpdates:withCapInsets:. UIScreen also has -snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:.
>
> Unlike UIView's -drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:, these
>   methods return a UIView object. If you are looking for a new snapshot
>   view, use one of
>   these methods. **It will be more efficient than calling
>   -drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates: to render the view contents into a bitmap image yourself**. You can use the returned view
>   as a visual stand-in for the current view/screen in your app. For
>   example, you might use a snapshot view for animations where updating a
>   large view hierarchy might be expensive.

Answer (score 3):

There is a third method for taking a snapshot that is much much quicker than either of these but it returns a `UIView`.

`- (UIView *)snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:(BOOL)afterUpdates`

If you are just using the snapshot to place as a background "image" etc... then I'd use this instead.

However, this is only available for iOS8.

To use it just do...

```
UIView *snapshotView = [someView snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:YES];
```

Comment: Then how can we get UIImage from this View.  we will use draw method here too?

Comment: This was written before you gave any specific details. Please could you answer my comment on your question.

Comment: A UIView which contain UIPageViewController. And I added array of images to pageViewController. Now i want to get screen shot of the UIView.

Comment: @AltafBangash But why a screenshot? If you have the images already (in the array) why would you then put them on the screen and take a screenshot? Why not just use the image from the array?

Comment: No no. I want to create video with animation like zooming, page rotating etc.

Comment: Oh, I see. That makes sense now. Really you should start your question there. If you start with "What's the fastest way to take a screenshot" then you will get people telling you how to take screenshots. If you start with "I have some animations on screen and want to a capture them into a video" then you will get people showing you how to capture animations into a video. Ask the question you want to ask not the question you think you should ask.

Comment: should I ask another question?

Answer (score 2):

This Method will return you A snapshot images of particular view

```
-(UIImage *)createSnapShotImagesFromUIview
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(view.frame.size.width,view.frame.size.height));
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [mapView.layer renderInContext:context];
    UIImage *img_screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
     return img_screenShot;
}
```